# Devexpress xtragrid column set mask with repositoryItemTextEdit

Tags: vb.net, formatting, repository, devexpress

I'm using devexpress 11.1.4. version also xtraGrid control, my code is vb.net
I have set repositoryItemTextEdit to display mask into grid column. I whant to set date format:
                            "dd.mm.yyyy "

At the time of typing looks good , however when cells lose focus it changes in format:
                            "mm.dd.yyyy"

Also sometimes they just emptied or when i choose for example: 
                                        10.05.2015. 
it change the value that it looks like this:                                   01.05.2015.
I do not know why

Here is my code:

```
    Public dateWithTextEdit As RepositoryItemTextEdit = New RepositoryItemTextEdit


        dateWithTextEdit .Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = True
        dateWithTextEdit .Mask.AutoComplete = XtraEditors.Mask.AutoCompleteType.Strong
        dateWithTextEdit .Mask.MaskType = XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.DateTime
        dateWithTextEdit .Mask.EditMask = "dd.mm.yyyy"

        DGV.RepositoryItems.Add(dateWithTextEdit )

          DGV.DataSource = dataTable


        With dgvVIEW

            .OptionsBehavior.AllowAddRows = DefaultBoolean.True
            .OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.NewItemRowPosition.Top
            .OptionsBehavior.AllowDeleteRows = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True


            .Columns(0).Name = "PROMDDOK"
            .Columns(0).FieldName = "PROMDDOK"
            .Columns(0).Caption = "DATUM DOKUMENTA"
            .Columns(0).ColumnEdit = dateWithTextEdit 
            .Columns(0).Visible = True
            .Columns(0).Width = 120


        End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem no. 1.: your edit mask is `dd.mm.yyyy`. `mm` stands for minutes, you have to use `dd.MM.yyyy`.

If this doesn't help, set the column's display format as well.
Code in C#:

```
columns[0].DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
columns[0].DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

Comment: Ok, now date is ok but it also displaying zeros like this 10.12.2015. 00:00:00

Comment: What did you change? Both things or just the first problem? I would suggest droping AutoComplete setting and changing MaskType to DateTimeWithAdvancingCarret.

Comment: I fix the problem. In database my column is set to be nvachar, but in the grid i set date, and that is the problem. Thank you. And why DateTimeWithAdvancingCarret?

Comment: My personal preference :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the DevExpress online documentation, [RepositoryItemTextEdit.Mask Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemTextEdit_Masktopic) is used to format cell values in edit mode.To format cell values in display mode, use solutions described in the [Formatting Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1473) document.